# scikit-learn / Gaussian Process is not scale invariant

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

I'm testing Gaussian Process regression with the library scikit-learn and am unhappy with the confidence intervals it gives me.
That made me realize that these were not scale invariant: if the function scales up (proportionally on every axis), the confidence intervals become way bigger.

Maybe pictures will explain it better :
(Sampled points in blue dots, true function is green, approximation is blue, confidence intervals = mean +/- 2sd  = grey area )

Function Scaled x 1:
[image: Function scaled x1]

Function scaled x 100:
[image: Function scaled x100]

Intuitively, these confidence intervals should be scale invariant right ? Do we obtain the same thing with other libraries ?

Thanks in advance !

PS : the code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu May 12 16:12:38 2016

@author: pierre
"""

import numpy as np
from sklearn import gaussian_process
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
pi=3.14

#Figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#Function definition
def f(x):
    return 3*((x-0.5)**2)*((np.cos(pi*x))**2)+0.2*np.sin(5*x)

# Coefficient of scale
nn=100 

#Real function points
x_real=np.linspace(0,nn,100)
y_real=nn*f(x_real/nn).ravel()

#Four points sampled
X = nn*np.atleast_2d([0.,.2,.5,1.]).T
y = nn*f(X/nn).ravel()

#For the approximation
x = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0, nn, 200)).T

#GP call
gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess()
gp.fit(X, y)  
y_pred, sigma2_pred = gp.predict(x, eval_MSE=True)

#Plots
ax.scatter(X,y,s=400) #Sampled points
ax.plot(x,y_pred) #Approximation
ax.fill_between(x.ravel(),y_pred-10*sigma2_pred,y_pred+10*sigma2_pred,color='black',alpha=0.1) #Confidence intervals
ax.plot(x_real,y_real) #True function
```

Comment: Can you please include the code that you're using to get your result? Can you please also include the code you're using to plot your graphs?

Comment: You need to take the square root of `sigma2_pred`. It's the mean *squared* error, so if you just use it directly, it won't scale linearly. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the square root of `sigma2_pred`, because that's the MSE, or mean *squared* error. The confidence interval should be based on its square root, like below:

```
#GP call
gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess()
gp.fit(X, y)  
y_pred, sigma2_pred = gp.predict(x, eval_MSE=True)
sd_pred = np.sqrt(sigma2_pred)

#Plots
ax.scatter(X,y,s=400) #Sampled points
ax.plot(x,y_pred) #Approximation
ax.fill_between(x.ravel(),y_pred-10*sd_pred,y_pred+10*sd_pred,color='black',alpha=0.1) #Confidence intervals
ax.plot(x_real,y_real) #True function
```

See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gp_regression.html#example-gaussian-process-plot-gp-regression-py) for the example on scikit-learn's documentation page. They also take the square root.